# In need of Disk Signature change method - Windows Server 2003 Enterp. x64 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, cluster

OS: Windows Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition SP2

I'm trying to change some Disk Signatures in order to recover a cluster.

I'm following this guide from Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/280425/recovering-from-an-event-id-1034-on-a-server-cluster

I don't have the "DumpCfg.exe" tool.
I tried with the "Diskpart" tool but in this OS it doesn't support "uniqueid disk" command.

Is there anything else i can do to change Disk Signature?
Or even better does anyone have the "DumpCfg.exe" for this OS to share it?

Contacting Microsoft about that tool hasn't helped because Windows Server 2003 is no longer supported as we know.

Comment: Extended support for this ended 18 months ago

Comment: We know about that but until we upgrade we need a solution to this. Also i don't get why this is getting downvoted.

Comment: Because if you'd read the words we put in front of you when you signed up for here you'd see that we're a site for professional sysadmins who inherently build and use supportable systems - we consider it deeply unprofessional to be working with unsupported systems. Imagine if you walked into a lounge of professional airline pilots asking about flying paying customers in a 14 year old unmaintained plane - they'd be concerned and unimpressed right - well we're pro's too.

Comment: I respect your opinion and i'm one of those people who don't want to work with unsupported systems. In the other hand at the moment this is critical and needs to be done, so i gave a shot asking here too.

Comment: This can be closed/deleted since noone is working with this OS anymore. I got it to work with a workaround.

Comment: @Kostas, if you did find a workaround, it might be worth posting it as the answer to your question. Regardless of the sentiments around using out-of-support software, you _did_ have this issue, and from your comment, you _did_ fix it. Although people should not (certainly in a professional context) be running the OS anymore, you, and likely others, are.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIR, another option is to use ClusterRecovery utility http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Exploring-the-Windows-Server-2003-Resource-Kit-Clusterrecoveryexe but I'm not sure about it.

There is a x64 dumpcfg.exe, but i guess it's hard to find it atm. However, ou can try to find it somewhere.